# Global variable declaration in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables

I have this code and I want to make the variable table a global variable but it doesn't work and I don't understand why, can someone help me?

```
      var table;
      function formatCustomerResults(obj) {
            var rows = Array();
            for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
                var item = obj[i];
                rows.push({
                    cell : [ item.guid, item.limittime, item.limitname ]
                });
            }

            console.log(rows);
            table = rows;

            return {
                total : obj.length,
                page : 1,
                rows : rows
            };
        }

        $.ajax({
            type : 'GET',
            url : 'http://localhost:6181/fintpWebServices/api/timelimits',
            dataType : 'json',
            success : function(data) {
                obj = data.timelimits;
                formatCustomerResults(obj);
            }
        });

         console.log(table);
```

Comment: What it gives in console? Error? blank? or anything else?

Comment: problem is that ajax is async, so table is still `null`

Comment: when your calling this `console.log(rows);` does that print anything on console?

Answer (score 2):

You are making an asynchronous call, you are acting like it is synchronous. You are calling console.log() before the callback is fired. Ajax 101 stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you're calling

```
console.log(table);
```

before **table** is actually populated by your AJAX call and the function **formatCustomerResults**. Remember that the 'A' of AJAX stands for 'asynchronous'.

Answer (score 0):

Actually table variable is set before your variables updates because
this code is `asynchronous` after using `ajax`

If you `console` after calling `formatCustomerResults` then it will show your `table`

```
        success : function(data) {
            obj = data.timelimits;
            formatCustomerResults(obj);
            console.log(table);// this will print data
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

I assume that the code you're showing is wrapped by a larger function? That would explain why it's being declared locally rather than globally.

To ensure that a variable is always declared globally, simply define it as a property of the window object, so remove the line

```
var table;
```

And replace

```
table = rows;
```

with

```
window.table = rows;
```

---

You could also simply write

```
table = rows;
```

without declaring table as a local variable, but it's good practice to explicitly define global variables as properties of the window object (which is what global variables are) so that it's clear to a reader that your definition of a global variable is intentional.

Comment: It's an ajax async issue, not a global variable issue.  You can see that from the fact that the declaration and later output of table are within the same scope.

Comment: @Archer - Yeah, I realized that after I had posted my response. The title of the question is misleading, and "it doesn't work and I don't understand why" didn't greatly clarify the issue.